# Avoid to insert same number by multiple users using transaction

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have couple insert queries which are merged into transaction scope. First of that insert is to create new product article number which is built by incrementing of the highest in table by one. Unfortunately I just noticed that mostly during tests if for instance two users from two different applications clicks button which trigger my transaction's method they could get same new product number and insert it. How can I avoid that situation?

Part of my transaction query below:

```
Public Sub ProcessArticle(ByRef artikel As ArticlesVariations)
        Dim strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            connection.Open()
            Using transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
                Try

                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbArtikel (Nummer) VALUES (@Nummer);Select Scope_Identity()", transaction.Connection)
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                cmd.Connection = connection
                                cmd.Transaction = transaction

                                 'Get next product number from table tbArtikel  (this will be new product number)'
                                 Dim NewArtNummer as String =  New DALArtikel().GetNewArtikelNumber(transaction)
                                 art.Nummer = NewArtNummer

                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nummer", art.Nummer)
'Get inserted product id for other diffrent inserts below'
 newArticleRowId = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) 

'....
other INSERTs queries to other tables ...
...'

       transaction.Commit()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    Throw 'Rethrow exception.'
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Article number is `varchar` column (I know it's bad etc) but it is how its implemented in current scope without possibility to change it.

Note that I cannot do any changes on the database level like new tables, trigger etc. (one exception is to create unique index on number column). I have to achieve that from application level.

I got three options on top of my mind and would like to take your advice which to choose:

**1st option:**

**a)** Make this column as unique column so when couple users inserting only one will insert the number but all of rest users will get error from catch about unique key violation so i could manage it somehow like make information to retry again.

**b)** Same as a) but also with isolation level set to ReadUncommited - from my point of view this will give me that when next users read newnumber they have chance to read from dirty numbers (so also from first user insertion) so there is chance they get next number.

**2nd option:**

Just to make transaction isolation to Read uncommitted - but this will not guaranty all same line users would get new number (probably worst out of all)

**3rd option:**

Heard something about TABLOCK but have no idea whether could be considered in this situation.

**...something else?**

At the moment I am considering to use 1st option -catch error and inform users.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: @Shnugo don't know but for sure not less than 2008

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2012 there was `SEQUENCE`, but this won't help you here. Obviously other people had the same problem therefore this was invented...

Comment: @Shnugo if that doesn't help what about my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed some of your older questions... This is obviously not so easy to solve. Therefore I have a completely different idea:

As your ProductNumber is a `VARCHAR` you could write there whatever you want?

Would it work to set a `GETDATE()` as string-literal (ISO 8601) into this column on insert and execute an `UPDATE` statement later, which will re-set the value to the correct numbering according to the order of insertion?

Strange and ugly anyway...

Comment: yes think i could, but you know it's funny this column but do we have to make it more funny with GETDATE solution :) ? hmm anyway can you show what you got? P.S I am think considering 1st option this will guaranty me unique so no duplication of number and just handle error for all other users.

Comment: @JimmyJimm Well, strange restrictions need strange suggestions :-) You might place a simple `GUID` string also, as long as there is `InsertTime` column which you can sort after. Such a GUID could be created in your application and you can use it in your process as unique key to this row. About your 1st option: Yes, you might do this... An error is quite unlikely, users won't see this to often...

Comment: your idea is also nice i like it and will think twice but i think i take my 1st option because there now i know there will be max 30 users working on this application version. So this error can occure only when minimum two users click button at the same time, so only for one will success but this situation rarely will take place. Right? About this unique when i make ALTER TABLE T_Artikel WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_T_Artikel_Nummer UNIQUE (Nummer) there is no way other users will insert right? I am asking to confirm as i am not db expert just to be sure.